# Iterating through columns, not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

What causes the code below to give the following error on line 8:

> Type error : 'Float' object is not iterable

```
for column in usable_columns:
    cardinality = len(np.unique(x_train[column]))
    if cardinality == 1:
        x_train.drop(column, axis=1) # Column with only one 
        # value is useless so we drop it
        x_test.drop(column, axis=1)
    if cardinality > 2: # Column is categorical
        mapper = lambda x: sum([ord(digit) for digit in x])
        x_train[column] = x_train[column].apply(mapper)
        x_test[column] = x_test[column].apply(mapper)
   x_train.head()
```

Comment: check `for column in range(usable_columns):` in 1st line

Comment: The error raised means the `x` object at line 8 is not iterable (e.g., a list, a dictionnary) as it's a float.  what is `x_train[column]` supposed to be?

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score -1):

A for loop can only function if the number of times it iterates is a whole number.
whatever the variable `column` is, its being stored as a float not an integer (i.e. 3.0 instead of 3) Assuming that `column` is a whole number, either use `column=int(column)`before the for loop or type `for int(column) in usable_columns` as your for loop